# Play framework migration mistakes

Tags: playframework, migration, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

After a migration from Play 2.0.4 to Play 2.1.1 I get the following error:

```
[error] /home/xxx/project/app/controllers/Application.scala:489: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[contents.Entry]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[contents.Entry]
[error]     Ok(views.html.shareKnowledge(contentForm, loadEntries(Option(request.user.id), Option(request.user.id), None, None), Map("deleteButton"->"show")))
```

The corresponding line in the HTML template is

```
@(contentForm: Form[contents.Entry], entries: Array[contents.Entry], streamDisplayOptions: Map[String,String])
```

I simply passed a form...

I read http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Migration
but I still do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like ther has been a mix of Java and Scala during your migration.

`play.api.data.Form[contents.Entry]` is used for Scala.

`play.data.Form[contents.Entry]` is used for Java.

If you followed the [migration guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Migration) then you probably did this:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
   javaCore, javaJdbc, javaEbean
)
```

But since you have a Scala project then you should also have read the paragraph after that:

> The **mainLang** parameter for the project is not required anymore. The main language is determined based on the dependencies added to the project. If dependencies contains **javaCore** then the language is set to **JAVA** otherwise **SCALA**. Notice the modularized dependencies in the **appDependencies** section.

This means that your `appDependencies` should look like this:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
   jdbc
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the reason. I expected Play to be primarily Scala based now so that such misleading docs could not occur any more... good to know